# Pyautogui - When using code that use special keys, the key seem stuck at times

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting a weird behavior while using pyautogui hotkey; where the special key used at times does "stick" and cause the subsequent text printed with pyautogui.typewrite() function to be printed incorrectly.

For example, this statement ran on OSX will cause shift to stick at random; causing the output to be printed capitalized.

```
pyautogui.hotkey("command", "shift", "f")
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.typewrite("reference_file2.txt")
```

This will open the "recents" window in Finder, wait 3 seconds then will type a filename which should (or should not be) in the recents window. Sometimes the output of `typewrite` is printed like if Shift key was pressed.
So instead of

```
reference_file2.txt
```

You will see

```
REFERENCE_FILE@>TXT
```

which is exactly what you get if you type the original string with Shift key pressed.

Is this a bug in the hotkey function of pyautogui? Or am I supposed to do something to ensure that the keys pressed with `hotkey` is released, before moving on with the next statement? The documentation of pyautogui specify that the hotkey function does equal to a keypress and keyrelease sequence, so no action should be required, right?

Comment: Yeah as far as I'm aware `hotkey` shouldn't require any additional commands after to release shift. Are your python and pyautogui installations up to date?

Comment: yes, both at the latest version. I suppose the issue may be due to the fact that when the keypress and keyrelease operations are executed in the `hotkey` function call; they go out of order. Not sure this is even fixable, without going in the pyautogui code itself